# How to simplify Environment.NewLine()?

Tags: c#, console-application

Hey StackOverflow users,

I'm working on a discord bot in C#. To keep my code clean, I'd like to use a function that adds more lines to a string.

An example of what I want to avoid is:

```
Description = $"Hey { username }! {Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine}{funMsg[randomNumber]}",
```

What I tried to do is:

```
public string inertlines(int i)
    {
        string st = "";
        for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
        {
            st += Environment.NewLine();
        }
        return st;
    }
```

The visual studio compiler gives an error regarding the NewLine statement. "Non-invocable member 'Environment.NewLine' cannot be used like a method.

I'd really appreciate it if someone could tell me what do to avoid this and/or another method that could replace the Environment.NewLine() methode.

Finally I want to clearify that this is NOT a duplicate. For new programmers this post does explain alot more of a more specific problem. The post that got compared to mine had the same SOLUTION, however, not the same problem. It's even a whole different SUBJECT. On top of that, starters could copy the solution to easialy add extra lines to a string or understand how functions work better, as Environment.NewLine() is a well known and easy to understand methode under newer programmers.

Thanks in advance,
Jelle

Comment: NewLine isnt a method just get rid of the parathesis, it should just be Environment.NewLine

Comment: Sometimes the simple things in life amaze you. Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: Discord doesn't care what your operating system's preferred new line character is.  It makes no sense to use `Environment.NewLIne` in this context in the first place.  The only real reason to use it is when writing out text files.

Comment: I'm using it because I'm embedding something using the EmbedBuilder class from Discord.net

Comment: @jellekeulemans That doesn't explain why you'd use your OS's preferred new line character, rather than the one Discord expects to be used, which isn't necessarily the same.

Answer (score 0):

The answer turns out to be really simple

```
public string insertlines(int i)
    {
        string st = "";
        for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
        {
//Environment.NewLine shouldn't have "()" in it's own class

            st += Environment.NewLine;
        }
        return st;
    }
```

The usage of this to create white lines in a string would be:

```
Console.WriteLine($"I want 2 {insertLines(2)} blanc lines under the 2"});
```

or to simplify that example:

```
Console.WriteLine("I want 2 " + insertLines(2) + " blanc lines under the 2");
```

For anyone reading this, please just use "\n" for new lines in a string. I've learned alot more about coding and think my question and answer were not the best, most helpful ones.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are immutable.  If you're going to concatenate many of them, for effiency's sake, instead try using StringBuilder:

```
public string insertlines(string s, int i)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append(s);  // create the string
    for (int c = 0; c < i; c++)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(""); // add a line each time
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: alright thanks! Didn't know that

Comment: StringBuilder is not always the best choice if you have few strings to concat.

Comment: @Steve Agreed, it really depends on the range of `i` in the case of this function.  As is so often the case, the right choice depends on the requirements.

Comment: you require a parameter 's' but you never use it? but other than that, this is how I would do it

Comment: and you don't need the empty string for AppendLine, just call AppendLine();

Comment: @Dave Please see the line after I declare the StringBuilder.  I append the input parameter `s` to add the main string first.

Comment: So you did sorry I was expecting to see in the string builder ctor and when I didn't I must have just mentally ignored that line after, sorry